# Reading ArrayList<String> key:value

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList using this format:

```
 [{"id":"480","value1":"xxx","value2":"yy"},{"id":"200","value1":"123abc","value2":"bbb"},{"id":"520","value1":"qwewer","value2":"eeee"}]

ArrayList<String> result = task.execute(itensUrl).get();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++) {
            ArrayList<String> currentList = result.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < currentList.size(); j++) {
                String s = currentList.get(1);
            }
        }
```

But I have this error:

**Incompatible types - required java.util.Arraylist  - Found: java.lang.String**

Comment: Your web service response is `String` and you are assigning to `ArrayList`

Comment: instead of `ArrayList<String> currentList = result.get(i);`, where you are basically writing arraylist = string, use `String currentList = result.get(i)`. you can also leave out the second for loop.

Comment: you need to deserialize it first

Comment: If you are using any json library, you can easily convert that json string to JSON Array of JsonObjects and parse them or use Jackson or Gson to data bind your json response to List of your custom objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for help, this is the result:

```
 ArrayList<String> result = task.execute(itensUrl).get();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++) {
            String currentList = result.get(i);
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(currentList);

            String id=jsonobject.optString("id");
            String value1=jsonobject.optString("name_user_feed");
            String value2=jsonobject.optString("establishment");
            System.out.println("id="+id);
            System.out.println("value1="+value1);
            System.out.println("value2=" +value2);

        }
```